# How to count number of active users (with percentage of all) for specifc user property?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I am looking for a way to count number of users witch apply to specific Firebase Analytics User Property in Firebase Console.

Specifically, I want to have below results:

User Property (e.g app version) | Count | % of all users

I've tried to do that in dashboard by filtering by User Property, but it shows only the count

Is it possible to achieve in Firebase Console?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in the Firebase console, but there are two other ways:

1. BigQuery - either query data directly or connect BigQuery to DataStudio for better visualization
2. If you have [upgraded project to the new analytics](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-google-analytics-upgrade.html) then you should be able to achieve that when you go to Explore > Analysis > Exploration. There you can add different dimensions, metrics and segments in the table:
   [image]

In your case you'd probably like to add your user property to the dimensions and put that dimension as the column. Exploration should automatically create both numeric and percentage division.